# Building Perl dependencies automatically

Tags: perl, automation

I'm trying to automate the installation of [this nagios plugin](https://github.com/jamesc/nagios-plugins-rabbitmq) with a shell script.  The pipeline of `make` -> `./Build installdeps` -> `make install` works, but the `./Build installdeps` step insists on requiring interaction at the terminal (mainly pressing enter).  I need it to run and install everything automatically.  The docs for Build (`Build help installdeps`) are useless and the standard tricks like passing in `-y` haven't got me anywhere.  I could write an expect script to handle it, but that seems a lot like taking a sledgehammer to a nut.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't this what `yes` is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following AKHolland's suggestion in comments, I solved this with the `yes` utility:

```
yes | ./Build installdeps
```